# Raspberry pi as Wireguard server and OpenVPN client: No connection to devices

Tags: openvpn, wireguard

I am trying and searching a lot but I am struggling with my scenario. I found some same posts, but there was no solution.

- I am using a Raspberry PI (192.168.10.100) to connect as a openvpn client to Nordvpn. This PI is the Gateway for my local clients to use the VPN connection
- I set up a Wireguard Server on the PI to receive connection from outside my network. The ports are open on my Router (192.168.10.1)
- When I am connecting my smartphone from my home network (not using the PI as VPN Gateway, using the ISP-IP) to the Wireguard server, I am connected and I am using the open vpn connection. I am getting the IP from Nordvpn. Everything works fine.
- When I am connecting the smartphone outside my LAN with mobile connection, I am connected to the VPN as well (getting the Nordvpn-IP) I am able to access internal devices like the router or any WLAN-repeater but I am not able to connect to the PI via SSH or HTTP.

It seems, that PI is not accepting the connection from the Wireguard connection.

Can anyone. help me please. Here is my configuration:

Kernel IP routing table:

```
 - Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref   
   Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         10.8.2.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
   0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
   5.180.62.99     192.168.10.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
   10.6.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
   10.8.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
   128.0.0.0       10.8.2.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
   192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

rc.local

```
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.10.100 lookup 9 
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 table 9 
sudo ip route add default via192.168.10.1 dev eth0 table 6 
sudo ip rule add fwmark 0x55 priority 1000 table 6 
sudo ip route flush cache 
sudo iptables -t filter -AFORWARD -i wg0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT sudo iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -o wg0 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820
fwMark = 0x55
PrivateKey = ...

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
PresharedKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
```

Comment: Did you setup routing? e.g. with the settings `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (else kernel will not route anything, and so your route tables will never be reached)

Comment: Hello, yes I did. I a m using the PI as a openvpn gateway for my local devices and therefore the forwarding is enabled